# Call functions of a contract deployed at a specific address from solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm dealing with inheritance and external calls of contract from within solidity. I have deployed my data structure and filled it at an address MapAdr

My code can me schemed as follow. In my DataStructure.sol I have:

```
interface Graph {
function getNeighbours(uint8 id) external view returns (uint8[8]);
function getOrder() external view returns (uint8);
function isNeighbour(uint8 strFrom, uint8 strTo) external view returns 
(bool success);

}

contract DataStructure is Graph {
....code....
uint8 order;
constructor (uint8 size) {
order = size;
}
....code...
}
```

I deploy this contract and I save the address to MapAdr=0x1234567...

Now I go to my other contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

import "./DataStructure.sol";


contract Data is Graph {
.....code....
DataStructure public data;

    constructor(address MapAdr) public {
    ....code...
    data = DataStructure(MapAdr);
    ....code...
    }
.....code....
}
```

But then DataStructure is deployed but it's address is not MapAdr.

There is a way to have an instance of the deployed contract at that specific MadAdr (so with that exactly data inserted in that datastructure) so I can query it's storage ?

The idea is to deploy several DataStructure contracts with different data inserted and then referiing to one specific when deploying Data contract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answers exactly your question, but I found this example very similar to what you are talking about, and I hope it can help you.

```
contract Admin {
  address private owner;

  function Admin() public { owner = msg.sender; }

  function getOwner() public returns (address) {
    return owner;
  }

  function transfer(address to) public {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    owner = to;
  }
}

contract Lottery {
  string public result;

  Admin public admin = Admin(0x35d803f11e900fb6300946b525f0d08d1ffd4bed);  // Admin contract was deployed under this address

  function setResult(string _result) public {
    require(msg.sender == admin.getOwner());
    result = _result;
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `Admin` contract is deployed under the address `0x35d...` and then it's used in the `Lottery` contract in the `admin` variable definition. Once you declare a variable as an instance of another contract, you can then use all the public interface of that contract. Check the `admin.getOwner();`execution.

Again, it's not following the same example as you mentioned, but it might be useful.

Hope it helps! ;-)

EDIT 1: Hardcoding the address of `Admin` instance in `Lottery` is probably a bad idea. This is just a very simple example. You might consider passing the `Admin` instance address as a parameter in the `Lottery` constructor instead. See comments below for more details.

Comment: Yes it's quite similar. The difference here is that the constructor is without parameters and I don't know why in this way it works. But in my case my constructor got a parameter so calling it as I do should be incorrect since my construct accept uint8 as parameter and not an address.

Comment: The contract's constructor is executed **just once** when the contract is deployed to the blockchain. So, if you have one `uint` argument, you will need to send it while deploying the contract. 
That's different from **referencing the contract instance** from other contract. You do so, just be referencing the `address` where the first contract was deployed, and you shouldn't need to send any of the constructor arguments, because the constructor of the first contract won't actually be called again. Makes sense?

Comment: Anyway, hardcoding the contract `address` in that way is probably not a good idea. Imagine you need to change the `Admin` instance in the future. It's simply not possible because the address is hardcoded in the `Lottery` contract. For these cases it's better to implement a `setAdmin();` method, or even send the address of the `Admin` instance as a parameter to the constructor while creating the `Lottery` instance.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. In my case hardcoding the address is OK in my case I'm aware of your warnings about. Can you give me more details about what is meaning "referencing the address where the first contract was deployed"? How can I do this? That's what I need from what I understand

Comment: Sure. To get your app "live" you will need to deploy contracts to the Ethereum blockchain. While developing you will probably be using a testnet, or a local running Javascript VM. In any of the cases, if you need to reference `contract1` from `contract2`, you will first need to create an instance of `contract1` (`Admin` in this example) by deploying it to the network. That will bring you an Ethereum address (similar to `0x35d...`), were the instance is available. You can now use that address from `contract2` to reference `contract1`.

Comment: You will basically need to split the deploy into these steps. Deploy `Admin` > get the address > reference from `Lottery` using previous address > Deploy `Lottery`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. But I've got a problem. I see that if your constructor doesn't accept parameters then calling it like Typecontract A = typecontract(address_reference) creates an istnace of your contract in the variable A. But if you have just one parameter which is not an address in the constructor then calling typecontract A = typecontract(address) is incorret and in my case it's exactly what is not working. I had to remove the parameters from the constructor and everything started to work. I don't get how it should work when you got parameters in the constructor.